# Collapse columns of table to tabs for mobile

Tags: javascript, css

```css
td{width:100px;text-align:center;}
.hh,th{font-weight:bold;color:magenta;}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="hh">OS</th>
        <th>Windows</th>
        <th>Linux</th>
        <th>iOs</th>
        <th>Android</th>
        <th>etc</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="hh">Option 1</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hh">Option 2</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hh">Option 3</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hh">Option 4</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have a table and I want to collapse it by column to tabs (for mobile).
Number of tabs equal to number of OS (in example it would be 5 tabs).
Like this https://www.shopify.com/pricing
[see 3 tabs by column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIsWO.png)

How I can realize this? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score -1):

Tables are not responsive by default so you need to trick a little, this link helped me out a lot and provides a solution for your problem.

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/